# What would make me still blocked by firewall even after using VPN connection?

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, firewall

As a developer, I need to connect to some daemons in several servers with custom non-standard ports.  Since right now I'm in a location with strict firewall, I thought that by using VPN, I could bypass the firewall.

So I try TunnelBear VPN.  Setup it in Linux. But the connection to port 7080 still fails after VPN is established.  I then try to setup OpenVPN in EC2 instance (port 443 is not blocked by the firewall).  Again, the connection to port 7080 fails after VPN is established.

I can make sure the daemon that listens to port 7080 is working fine.  If I use third party port scanner or open it from my phone using carrier network, it is working.  The problem may be in my Ubuntu.  I've  disabled UFW but no luck.  What would be things that may block the connection even after connected to VPN?

Comment: Is your system routing all traffic through VPN? Windows do this by default but not sure about Linux.

Comment: I can be sure that my ip address is from the VPN server.  DNS leak test also shows DNS from server's side.  But I'm not aware of any other leaks.

Comment: Run tcpdump on the ec2 filtered for your  VPN IP, ping the ec2 and see if your packets get there.  Then try a few other ports with `telnet <ec2ip> <port>` and see if they get there.

Comment: No response from tcpdump in EC2 server.  When I check using nmap to the server, port 7080 appears as "filtered".

Comment: Just realized when I do `traceroute`, the EC2 server is listed on the second line.  It went through IP like `10.x.x.1` before reaching EC2.  Doing port scan on it, looks like `10.x.x.1` is my target EC2. It this normal?

Comment: Yeah, EC2 instances have public and private addresses.  You have definitely opened the port in AWS firewall right?  Perhaps try `tcptraceroute` on port 7080, it give a clue where it is getting stuck.

Comment: Yes, I've opened all incoming and outgoing connections for the EC2 instance.  When I try to do `tcptraceroute` from my computer, except for `10.x.x.21`(yesterday was `10.x.x.1`), it only displays `* * * *`for the rest 29 lines.  Ops.. just realized that when using normal connection, `tcptraceroute` also display `10.x.x.21` in the first line.